# How to connect to Oracle database through my website using PHP? My data is hosted in AWS RDS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, database-connectivity

I am unable to connect to Oracle database hosted in AWS RDS through my website. 
Do we need Oracle client for that? If yes, how to implement that at our end?

I have this code:

```
<?php
$tns = " s1234fortify.cmqwhsydjmea.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com ";
$db_username = "S1234";
$db_password = "S1234";
try{
  $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I am getting this error:

> could not find driver

Comment: Would you expand your question to show your research and what code you have tried? I expect it is possible, and that people have tried it before. Do you plan to use PDO or the `oci` set of functions? I would suggest [starting here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oracle+php+pdo+aws).

Comment: I tried with this OCI functions ...

Comment: My question is : I have a website through which I want to connect to Oracle Dtabase I have created in RDS ,but it is failing to connect .I am able to connect to other database like my sql and sql but  for oracle I am facing the issue .I am able to connect to oracle through sql developer at my pc ,but when i try ruuning the php oci command it fails .I hope u got it ..let me know if any info is required .

Comment: if u have any code ,Please help with that ..

Comment: Yes, how did you install the `oci_` commands? How _exactly_ does it fail, what error do you get? Have you installed the Oracle client locally? Do you have the right module installed when you do `php -i` or `php -m`? Lots of questions, please answer them _all_.

Comment: I've added your comments (now deleted) into your question. Still need to know how you installed Oracle on this machine. Still need to know the output of the PHP commands above.

Comment: in which machine i need to install the oracle ..I have all the things in website ..can I install something there ?

Comment: Last comment, since this is still too broad. [Here is the process to install the Instant Client on Centos](https://awsadminz.com/enabling-php-with-oracle-support-with-oci8-in-rhel-centos-5-5-x86_64/), you'll have to do some web searching to see if it is possible on AWS.

Comment: checked ...found nothing ... Is there anyone who can help ?